# Consuming Amazon SimpleDB - IdentityPool not found

Tags: xamarin.forms.labs

I'm following the tutorial from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/aws/ and have created an AWS IdentityPool and modified the Policy Document for the unauthenticated identity as described, but when I run the downloaded sample project I get:

IdentityPool '{poolid}' not found

When I login to the Cognito Console, I can browse my IdentityPool (Federated Identities) and all appears to be valid

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The region specified in the example was useast1, whereas my identitypool was in uswest2.